# Notation of rules of a calculus in "Mathematical Logic" by Ebbinghaus

Tags: logic, notation, terminology

I have a basic question on the notation used in "Mathematical Logic":

Ebbinghaus writes rules of a calculus as $$\frac{\zeta_1,...,\zeta_n}{\zeta}$$ and by that he means that if the strings $\zeta_1,...,\zeta_n$ belong to some subset $Z \subset A_S^*$ then $\zeta$ also belongs to $Z$. Now on page $23$, in exercise $4.6$, Ebbinghaus writes $$\frac{}{\text{ }x\text{  }x\text{ }}$$ or $$\frac{y\text{   }t_i}{y\text{   }ft_1...t_n}$$. What does he mean by that? ($x \text{ }x$ is clearly not a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a *calculus* for the function $\operatorname{var}_S$ of **Def.4.5**.

The first rule ("premise-free") correspond to the fact that :

> for every variable $x : x \in \operatorname{var}(x)$.

There is no rule for the *constant* $c$, exactly because : $\operatorname{var}(c)=\emptyset$ and thus :

> for every variable $x : x \notin \operatorname {var}(c)$.

Finally, the second rule states that :

> if $x \in \operatorname{var}(t_i)$, then $x \in \operatorname{var}(ft_1 \ldots t_n)$, for every $t_i$.

---

The "formulae" derivable in the calculus are :

> $x \quad x$ : by 1st rule

and :

> $x \quad t$, where $t$ is a term like : $ft_1 \ldots t_n$, where $x \in \operatorname{var}(t_i)$, for some $i$ : by 2nd rule.

We **cannot** derive :

> $x \quad c$, for any $x,c$.

---

You can try with a little "experiment"; apply the rules to a language with :

- two variables : $x,y$
- a constant : $0$
- a (binary) *function* symbol : $+$

and see what happens.